# How does the python del function work without calling __getitem__

Tags: python, magic-methods, python-collections

In python, an object is subscriptable when it's class defines a

```
__getitem__(self, k)
```

method, allowing us to "get items" through the bracket syntax:

```
obj[k]
```

The syntax for the builtin del function is:

```
del(obj[k])
```

This deletes item k from (subscriptable) object obj. But apparently, without calling the special getitem method.

See example below

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, d):
...         self._d = d
...
...     def __getitem__(self, k):
...         print("Calling __getitem__")
...         return self._d[k]
...
...     def __delitem__(self, k):
...         del(self._d[k])
...
>>>
>>> a = A({1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'})
>>> a._d
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
>>> a[2]
Calling __getitem__
'two'
>>> del(a[2])
>>> # Note there was no "Calling __getitem__" print!
```

So it seems like before a[2] forwards the work to the getitem method, the interpreter is aware of the del context, and bypasses it, calling directly

```
a.__delitem__(2)
```

instead.

How does that work?

And most of all: Is this mechanism customizable?

Could I for example, write a function foo so that

```
foo(obj[k])
```

doesn't ever call

```
obj.__getitem__(k)
```

but instead, for example,

```
obj.foo(k)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del` is *not* a function. It can do this because it's not a function. This is *why* it's not a function. It's a keyword built into the language as part of the `del` statement.

To keep in mind that things like `del` and `return` aren't functions (and avoid unexpected precedence surprises), it's best to not put parentheses around the "argument":

```
del whatever
```

rather than

```
del(whatever)
```

---

`del` does not take an object and delete it. The thing to the right of `del` is not an expression to be evaluated. It is a [*target_list*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target-list), the same kind of syntax that appears on the left side of the `=` in an assignment statement:

```
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

To delete a *subscription* target like `obj[k]`, Python evaluates the expression `obj` and the expression `k` to produce two objects, then calls the `__delitem__` method of the first object with the second object as the argument. `obj[k]` is never evaluated as an expression, though pieces of it are.

---

This all relies on compiler and grammar support, and cannot be done for arbitrary user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your example code as though `del` were a function taking
arguments and assuming that the argument `a[2]` has to be processed first via
`__getitem__()`. But strictly speaking, `del` is a [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=del#the-del-statement). That means the language parser can treat it in a special
way – in other words, not necessarily like a function call.

We can use the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) package to get some hints about that. Note how the `del`
operation gets expressed directly as the very specific `DELETE_SUBSCR` operation.
It bypasses the `BINARY_SUBSCR` step used by the `len` example.

```
from dis import dis

def f(xs):
    del xs[2]

def g(xs):
    len(xs[2])

print('\n# del')
dis(f)
print('\n# len')
dis(g)
```

Output (summarized):

```
# del
0 LOAD_FAST                0 (xs)
2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
4 DELETE_SUBSCR
6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
8 RETURN_VALUE

# len
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
 2 LOAD_FAST                0 (xs)
 4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
 6 BINARY_SUBSCR
 8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
10 POP_TOP
12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
14 RETURN_VALUE
```